# error with $_POST

Tags: php, mysql

Well, I have the problem narrowed down to one group of code, and here it is:

```
<?php
  if( isset($_POST['submit'])){
    **if($_POST['shortsitename'] == ""){$newshortsitename = $shortsitename;}else{ $newshortsitename = $_POST['shortsitename'];}
    if($_POST['organization'] == ""){$neworganization = $organization;}else{$neworganization = $_POST['organization'];}
    if($_POST['city'] == ""){$newcity = $city;}else{$newcity = $_POST['city'];}
    if($_POST['state'] == ""){$newstate = $state;}else{$newstate = $_POST['state'];}**

      $user_lvl = \Fr\LS::getUser("user_lvl");
      $updateGroup = \Fr\LS::updateGroupinfo(
        array(
          "shortsitename" => $newshortsitename,
          "organization" => $neworganization,
          "city" => $newcity,
          "state" => $newstate
        ), $user_lvl
      );
      if($updateGroup === "success"){
        echo "<label>Success.</label>";
      }elseif($updateGroup === false){
        echo "<label>Update failed.";
      }
  ?>
```

Basicly, I have a form that lets user change the information about their organization in a database. However, when I have this code in the site, it returns internal server error 500. When I removed this block of code, the site displays fine. My main question is, is the code that is bolded correct, or did I miss word it?

**Edit: It's not letting me bold the code, but there are "stars" around the code I am talking about.

Comment: You are missing the closing `}` for `if( isset($_POST['submit'])){`. Add it before your closing tag `} ?>`

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I looked at that code for idk how long trying to find the error... Thanks for the help!

Comment: start using an IDE it will point out syntax errors to you

Answer (score 1):

Your Update failed `<label>` tag does not have a closing `</label>` and I think you are missing 2 `}` on the end. Is `$shortsitename` defined above?

```
<?php
if( isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //**
    if($_POST['shortsitename'] == ""){
        $newshortsitename = $shortsitename;
    }else{ 
        $newshortsitename = $_POST['shortsitename'];
    }
    if($_POST['organization'] == ""){
        $neworganization = $organization;
    }else{
        $neworganization = $_POST['organization'];
    }
    if($_POST['city'] == ""){
        $newcity = $city;
    }else{      
        $newcity = $_POST['city']; 
    }           
    if($_POST['state'] == ""){
        $newstate = $state;}else{
            $newstate = $_POST['state'];
        }
        //**
        $user_lvl = \Fr\LS::getUser("user_lvl");
        $updateGroup = \Fr\LS::updateGroupinfo(
            array(                      
                "shortsitename" => $newshortsitename,
                "organization" => $neworganization,
                "city" => $newcity,         
                "state" => $newstate        
            ), $user_lvl                
        );                          
        if($updateGroup === "success"){
            echo "<label>Success.</label>";

        }elseif($updateGroup === false){
            echo "<label>Update failed.";
        }                           
?>
```

Above is reformatted version of your code.

Comment: already answered by comment

Comment: @Abdulla `Comment !== Answer`